# Best Method for reading a YAML response in .NET?

Tags: .net, yaml, pandastream

Weve recently been trying to work on an application that uses pandastream to encode our videos, we are sending the videos successfully, and the response that we get back is in YAML, however the only tool that we can find (YAML for .NET) is not parsing the file.  Has anyone else ran into this, or have any insight on the best practice for parsing a YAML file in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update, i found a rather useful, but not too elegant as yet solution for my issue.

[yamldotnet](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=235362)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried, http://www.codeplex.com/yaml?