# Any way to read .yml files as easely as .xml files?

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing, yaml

I am using this example to read .xml files in a windows form,

```
Try
    If System.IO.File.Exists(Pathto & "\MinecartMania\MinecartManiaConfiguration.xml") = True Then
        FileFlag(1) = True
        MinecartManiaCoreConfiguration = XDocument.Load(Pathto & "\MinecartMania\MinecartManiaConfiguration.xml").Root
        For Each option As XElement In MinecartManiaCoreConfiguration.Elements

            If (option.Name = "LoggingMode") Then
                LoggingMode = CStr(option.Value)
            End If
            If (option.Name = "MinecartsKillMobs") Then
                MinecartsKillMobs = CBool(option.Value)
            End If
```

Is there anything similar for .yml files?
I looked around but i found only complicated methods i can't understand!

EDIT: C'mon people! Can't be that hard!!!

Comment: Whats a YML? Can you show sample YML file?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the tools under "C#/.NET" at [yaml.org](http://yaml.org/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Method for reading a YAML response in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189435/best-method-for-reading-a-yaml-response-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the structure, you can probably start out with a binary reader and start from there. The markings in the site you can look for are

Start of document "---"

Individual entry "-"

Property Name and value "{property_name}": {value}

arrays begin with "[]" next to a property "{property_name}" : []

I'd start by parsing the file, then I would use .net's dynamic type to build the model at run time by adding each new property as they are encountered.

From there you should have a generic collection of your dynamic type and should be able to query the parsed yml file using lambda or linq